# String sorting algorithm in FAST ESP

Tags: sorting, fast-esp, microsoft-search-server

Is anyone aware of sorting logic in FAST ESP engine ver. 5.3? How special characters are handled and how sorting of Japanese and Chinese words is performed?

Here are top 8 of search results which were sorted in ascending order:

```
門
¿ c
¿ c¡a «n »c ‹e ›r § ¶~#15
¿ c¡a «n »c ‹e ›r § ¶~#44
¿ c¡a «n »c ‹e ›r § ¶~#45
§ word document4
門 他の他の
門 他の他の 2
```

Does it mean that `門` character is omitted from sorting scope?

And these are top 10 of search results sorted in descending order:

```
他の門そ他の門
の他
他の
そ他の門そ他の
そ他の門門門
そ他他そ
そ
そ他
СЌРЅРІР»гЃќд»
РјР°СЂС†РїРёРѕСЂС‹РІ
```

It appears that last two results with Cyrillic symbols are handled correctly but then ambiguity is observed when `そ` result is put between `そ他` and `そ他他そ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is handled in alphabetical order in Latin languages and Greek, but in the case of JKC languages, you need to set up properly the document configuration to be able to handle those languages. Also you need to install the tokenization for those languages too. Microsoft provides the patches to include tokenization and dictionary for each of those languages. I think that would be really useful to verify that the search engine and documents in the collection are properly configured.